# Spline interpolation - 3D analysis

Tags: interpolation, 3d-analyst, spline

From the help document, spline interpolation is supposed to produce a surface runnin through the exact input point. i have about 100 point and run spline interpolation. i also extract the interpolated value from the spline surface at the 100 input points location and compared with the original value. i found that there are some siginificant difference between the interpolated value and original value. Did anybody came across this before? Why the spline surface does not run through the input points. P.S. i used tension spline with 15 as weight and 12 as searching points, cellsize 20m of 3D analyst of ArcGIS10.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to make clear whether it is the 3D Analyst of ArcGIS for Desktop that you are using (and at what version), please?

Comment: Is that for all points or just for some? I take it you are referring to http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000006q000000.htm as the *documentation*.

Comment: Test data with 100 random points which lead to error with your parameters would be appreciated.

Comment: to user30184 could you make it more specific? did not get you.

Comment: It is hard to say why the spline surface does not run through the input point and what to do for correcting this obvious error without doing the same thing that you did with similar source data and same processing parameters.